# Include Android Google Play Services failed?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I'm trying to include [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) in my project to use [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), based on steps provided by Google in this link [Google Play Service Setup](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) 
But unfortunately, the include process always ends with a red cross next to the included project as in the next image:
[image]

**How to solve this ?**

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse after having added the library. I have run into this issue before, and things behave better after restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Another thing, the documentation states copying the library to the workspace and NOT linking to it in the SDK folder.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late but I recently had this problem and what solved my problem was simply making sure that the library and project were on the same partition. Once i put them on the same partition it started working fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) Nothing is late at all! There's always someone, somewhere, sometime, who has an issue, and maybe your answer will help him in solving his issue .... Thanks again :)